# Android Emulator -http-proxy -dns-server won't work

Tags: android, proxy, dns

I'm getting this warning on my school PC:

```
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get a URL: 7 (Error)
emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: failed to get the latest version, skipping check (current version '24.4.1'
```

Even after setting up -http-proxy and -dns-server, I'm still getting this warning that doesn't allow me to launch an emulator with ARM image on it.

UPD: Resolved by "-dns-server 8.8.8.8" (just forgot to put the IP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without setting up & installing HAXM and enabling Intel virtualization technology (VT-x) from BIOS, Your emulator will not launch. Check this link for more [How to enable intel vt-x](http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/)

Comment: Finally I've launch it...setting an -dns-server 8.8.8.8